# How much do encounter rates vary by location when fishing?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

I've had a go the old rod in Pokémon blue in a couple of locations. It appears to me that it's only possible to catch Magikarp with this rod, is that true?

In general, including with the good rod and super rod, does the encounter rate vary by location? Or will e.g. the good rod always have the same encounter rates regardless of where you fish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Old Rod](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Old_Rod) can give you only Magikarp. As Bulbapedia states:

> In Gen 1 the only Pokémon that can be fished out by the Old Rod is Magikarp, all of which would be level 5.

Encounter rates do change by location, for example, according to Bulbapedia for Pokemon Red/Blue:

##### [Route 21](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kanto_Route_21#Generation_I)

**Good Rod**: 50% Poliwag, 50% Goldeen
**Super Rod**: 25% Shellder, 25% Horsea, 25% Goldeen, 25% Staryu

##### [Pallet Town](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pallet_Town#Generation_I)

**Good Rod**: 50% Poliwag, 50% Goldeen
**Super Rod**: 50% Poliwag, 50% Tentacool

Comment: Thankyou! I looked on bulbapedia but I didn't see that. I already bought the Magikarp in the pokecentre at Mt Moon, so that old rod is going in the computer!

Comment: 500 pokedollars for a Magikarp is my definition of a fraud :)

Comment: Haha it was nothing compared to the amount of exp I had to sink in to get him to level 20